# difference between two different ways to query data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure if I understand it wrong or if the codes below are wrong but from my understanding the following codes should give the same output:

```
transactions[transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '21' | transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '22']
```

and

```
transactions.query("date.str.slice(11, 13) == '21' | date.str.slice(11, 13) == '22'")
```

I get an error when I try the first code:

```
transactions[transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '21' | transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '22']
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

But when using `.query` method i get no errors:

```
transactions.query("date.str.slice(11, 13) == '21' | date.str.slice(11, 13) == '22'")
```

How can i change the first code without using the `query` method and getting the same output as the second code with the `query` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of Python's operator precedence. `|` is more important than `==`, so `'21' | transactions['date'].str[14:16]` gets evaluated *before* `transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '21'`.

To fix the first line of code, simply add parentheses around the `==` conditions:

```
transactions[(transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '21') | (transactions['date'].str[14:16] == '22')]
```

Or, if you prefer, use `.eq` instead of `==`:

```
transactions[transactions['date'].str[14:16].eq('21') | transactions['date'].str[14:16].eq('22')]
```